# Неправильно высчитывается цепная дробь, что делать?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Неправильно высчитывается цепная дробь, что делать?

на картинке, то что должно получиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def confract(num):
    den = 1
    a, q = divmod(num, den)
    t = den
    res = [a]
    while q != 0:
        next_t = q
        a, q = divmod(t, q)
        t = next_t
        res.append(a)
    return res

m = 21299881
print(confract(sqrt(m))
```

получается вот такой массив(по началу все нормально, но после 13 чисел массивы расходятся в значениях):

[4615.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 7.0, 1.0, 27.0, 1.0, 6.0, 1.0, 2.0, 13.0, 3.0, 1.0, 7.0, 1.0, 3.0, 8.0, 1.0, 5.0, 1.0, 9.0, 2.0]

Answer (score 5):

проблема в точности `float` поэтому лучше использовать `Decimal`

```
import decimal

def confract(num):
    den = 1
    a, q = divmod(num, den)
    t = den
    res = [int(a)]
    while q != 0:
        next_t = q
        a, q = divmod(t, q)
        t = next_t
        res.append(int(a))
    return res

m = decimal.Decimal(21299881)
print(confract(m ** decimal.Decimal("0.5")))
```

вывод:

> ```
> [4615, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 7, 1, 27, 1, 6, 1, 2, 12, 23, 1, 8, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 43, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 11, 1, 7, 1, 4, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]
> ```

Comment: кстати на Fractions еще сильнее точность падает, чем на float :(

Answer (score 4):

тоже точность плывет :(

на 14 члене уже не то

```
[4615, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 7, 1, 27, 1, 6, 1, 2, 13, 3, 1, 7, 1, 2, 1, 12, 2, 2, 4, 10, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1]
```

вот код

```
import math

def confract(num, depth = 10):
    res = []
    for _ in range(depth):
        res.append(math.floor(num))
        fraction = num - math.floor(num)
        num = 1 / fraction

    return res


m = 21299881
print(confract(math.sqrt(m), 20), sep=' ')
```

а с `decimal` все нормально

```
[4615, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 7, 1, 27, 1, 6, 1, 2, 12, 23, 1, 8, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 39, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1]
```

вот код

```
import decimal

def confract(num, depth = 10):
    res = []
    for _ in range(depth):
        res.append(int(num))
        fraction = num - int(num)
        num = 1 / fraction

    return res


m = 21299881
print(confract(decimal.Decimal(m).sqrt(), 40), sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к предыдущим ответам, мне стало интересно - а вдруг достаточно будет и встроенных расширенных типов `float` из библиотеки `Numpy` и точный тип `Decimal` в данной задаче не нужен? Взял за основу код Zhihar:

```
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal

def confract(num, maxlen=14):
    res = np.zeros(maxlen, dtype=np.int)
    for i in range(maxlen):
        n = np.floor(num)
        res[i] = n
        fraction = num - n
        num = 1 / fraction
    return res

m = 21299881
maxlen=100
types = [Decimal, np.float32, np.float64, np.float128]
res = np.zeros((len(types), maxlen), dtype=np.int)
for i,t in enumerate(types):
    r = confract(np.sqrt(t(m)), maxlen)
    res[i,:] = r

exact_result = res[0,:]
print('Расхождение с Decimal после элемента:')
for i,t in enumerate(types[1:], 1):
    print(t.__name__, '-', np.argwhere(res[0,:] != res[i,:])[:1][0][0])
```

На выходе:

```
Расхождение с Decimal после элемента:
float32 - 6
float64 - 13
float128 - 16
```

Таким образом, даже использования довольно длинного типа `Numpy.float128` недостаточно для данной задачи - расхождение будет уже после 16-го элемента.